# Stop youtube kids for child

Tags: youtube, google-account

My 12 year old needs to access full version of **youtube**.

However whenever she goes to youtube.com website (in any browser) using it redirects her to https://www.youtubekids.com  I have tried everything to allow her access to youtube.com but nothing seems to work.

She is setup to be managed by me as her parent in **goolge family link app.**  I tried  to remove her from being managed by me or to enable youtube from within the app but cannot find any settings for this that are mentioned in the user guides

When I goto https://myaccount.google.com for her account it says[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you will not be able to change this behaviour. Similar issues have been recorded again and again.

**Google picks her date of birth initially entered in your account**. Try changing that although I don't think it will work.

As a workaround she could **temporarily log-out** from the Google account **or open a new private window** to have full access.

Another alternative is to **create a new member** in your family account providing a new birthday, thus an older age *(say 18 )* and have her use that on instead.

---

Editor Note: There is a specific official help center for this topic: [Youtube Kids Parental Guide](https://support.google.com/youtubekids)

Comment: Seems like an alternative worked for you. If you find the time it would be interesting (out of curiosity) to know the alternative you ended up using. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the help - Using a  'new private window' was the easiest option that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's because her account age is set to be under 13 it does not allowed her to access normal YouTube, you'll either have to create a new account which the age is set to be over 13 or change the accounts age by contacting Google/YouTube support